# Parse a URL querystring

Tags: php, string, query-string, text-parsing

I have a string like:

```
$q = "menu=true&submenu=true&pcode=123456&code=123456";
```

I want to get the value of `pcode = 123456` and `code = 123456`.

How can I get this?

Comment: Where do you get the string from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `parse_str` function if it's not from url (then use `$_GET` array)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: +1 Even though this doesn't exactly address the stated concern, it certainly seems to be valid advice. We don't want Bobby Tables dropping in for tea.

Answer (score 3):

Use explode to get array from a string.

```
explode('&',$q);
```

It will explode string on every & character and return pieces in an array.

Answer (score 1):

See [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Answer (score 0):

Please use php explode functions to do it

ex:

```
   <?php

$q ="menu=true&submenu=true&pcode=123456&code=123456" ;
$pieces = explode("&",$q);

print_r($pieces);

foreach($pieces as $key=>$value){
    $newVarible[]=explode("=",$value);


}
print_r($newVarible);

?>
```

Comment: this ll return an array of value pcode=123456 but i need pcode, ccode as keys and 123456, 123456 as values...! :(

Answer (score 0):

```
    $q ="menu=true&submenu=true&pcode=123456&code=123456" ;

    // parse str values into an array called $pairs
    parse_str($q, $pairs);

   // loop through $pairs and display all values
    foreach ($pairs as $key => $val) {
       echo "$key => $val\n";
    }
```