# Parse a string to array

Tags: php, string, parsing

I have a string

```
$str = "recordsArray[]=3&recordsArray[]=1";
```

Is there any simple way to make this to an array other than exploding
this string at `&`? Im expecting a result like this `print_r($str);`

```
//expecting output
array('0' => '3','1' => '1');
```

Comment: Looks more like a regular expression would work better then unserializing. There's no content that looks to be serialized in your question.

Comment: You could also use `parse_str()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I split a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788178/how-can-i-split-a-string)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is: [`parse_str`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/parse_str); Example ([Demo](http://codepad.org/1T6blMIN)):

```
parse_str("recordsArray[]=3&recordsArray[]=1", $test);
print_r($test);
```

Comment: parse_str("recordsArray[]=3&recordsArray[]=1",$str);
           print_r($str);exit; //Working :)

Answer (score 2):

Use preg_match_all like this:

```
$str = "recordsArray[]=3&recordsArray[]=1";
if ( preg_match_all('~\[\]=(\d+)~i', $str, $m) )
   print_r ( $m[1] );
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 1
)
```

Comment: +1 Thank you it worked ! ..but i prefer alex's answer..its simple